# How important instruction scheduling for PTX?

Tags: compiler-construction, cuda, parallel-processing, compiler-optimization

As i understand, the main advantage of PTX to give you access couple of specific instructions. It is also intermediate level programming language. It means, nvidia compiler doesn't execute straight PTX code. It re-compile PTX codes into hardware specific assembly.

When we consider these all terms, In short, I'm wondering is there any effects of PTX instruction scheduling? Also if we re-schedule PTX code, can we obtain performance or can see any effects?

Thanks in advance

Comment: "nobody can see final assembly code"  Not true.  There are [cuda binary utilities](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-binary-utilities/index.html#axzz3G9iREsxb) that allow you to dump the assembly.  PTX instructions are not scheduled.  SASS instructions are scheduled.  PTX is an intermediate code.  So it's unclear what you mean by "instruction scheduling for PTX".

Comment: @RobertCrovella thank you. I changed a bit text. But my question is if we schedule current PTX code, is it possible to obtain speed up or any effect? Because we don't have permit to change cuda assembly code, right?

Comment: @JackOLantern thank you for reply. I think i couldn't ask question. Because i am not asking ptx optimization. My question if i re-schedule on PTX or can i obtain any result (bad or ill)? Because i don't know what will compiler generate real assembly code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The final arbiter of instruction scheduling is the CUDA driver, which contains an optimizing compiler that translates PTX to microcode for your GPU.  If instruction scheduling is the only benefit that you anticipate from using PTX, you aren't going to get much return on your investment.  It may even be counterproductive by confusing the heuristics used by the compiler in the CUDA driver.

Comment: It would seem advantageous to clarify that the PTXAS component of the compiler which compiles PTX into machine code, can either be invoked as part of offline compilation, in which case the CUDA driver merely loads the generated binary machine code, or as part of online (JIT) compilation, in which case the PTXAS component inside the driver performs compilation from PTX to SASS as you described.

Comment: Thank you everyone. I understood situation of PTX for scheduling. But for me PTX is still weird. If i can't do many things which i can do in assembly, why i need to learn/use this language for future? Better to wait ever-evolving CUDA compiler.

By the way, this paper is recently published. PTX Instruction scheduling, http://www.ece.ubc.ca/~aamodt/papers/tgrogers.micro2013.pdf